# Geopandas: how to read a csv and convert to a geopandas dataframe with polygons?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I read a `.csv` file as a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('myFile.csv')
df.head()
    BoroName    geometry
0   Brooklyn    MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.97604935657381 40.63127590...
1   Queens      MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.80379022888098 40.77561011...
2   Queens      MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.8610972440186 40.763664477...
3   Queens      MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.75725671509139 40.71813860...
4   Manhattan   MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.94607828674226 40.82126321...
```

I want to convert it to a geopandas dataframe.

```
import geopandas as gpd
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs).set_geometry('geometry')
```

but I get the following error

```
TypeError: Input must be valid geometry objects: MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.97604935657381 40.631275905646774, -73.97716511994669 40.63074665412933,....
```

Answer (score 37):

Geopandas seems to be unable to convert a geometry column from a pandas dataframe.

**Solution number 2**

Try applying the shapely `wkt.loads` function on your column before converting your dataframe to a geodataframe.

```py
from shapely import wkt

df['geometry'] = df['geometry'].apply(wkt.loads)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs='epsg:4326')
```

Good luck!

---

**Do not use - crashes spyder and jupyter kernel for some people**

Solution number 1: Try loading the csv directly with geopandas

```
gdf = gpd.read_file('myFile.csv')
gdf.crs = 'epsg:4326'
```

Comment: number 2 works for me. number 1 kills my jupyter-notebook kernel for some reason

Comment: Number 1 also crashes Spyder kernel

Comment: Number 2 works great

Answer (score 32):

You could also try this:

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.longitude, df.latitude)
)
```

This will convert those lat/long columns to points

Comment: But where within the dataframe presented are the columns latitude and longitude?

Comment: The correct order when using geometric coordinates with `points_from_xy` is `points_from_xy(longitudes, latitudes)`.

Answer (score 1):

Dudes, there are wkt geometry strings in the original dataframe, not xy columns, so i would suggest read this:
[DataFrame with WKT Column to GeoPandas Geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66786737/dataframe-with-wkt-column-to-geopandas-geometry)

Answer (score 0):

Geopandas puts a geometry column at the end if you load directly. Found this out by experimenting with column names and it worked