# DataFrame with WKT Column to GeoPandas Geometry

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I wrote a script to query a PostGIS database, returning a Pandas dataframe like this:

```
   ID  ...                          WKT
0   1  ...  LINESTRING(1.5047434 42.6319022,1.5053385 42.6...
1   2  ...  LINESTRING(1.5206333 42.5291144,1.5206306 42.5...
```

Now I am trying to write this into a shapefile with GeoPandas, according to their [documentation](https://geopandas.org/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html):

*We use shapely.wkt sub-module to parse wkt format*:

```
from shapely import wkt

df['Coordinates'] = geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df['Coordinates'])
```

But when I tried to do the same, I got:

```
AttributeError: type object 'GeoSeries' has no attribute 'from_wkt'
```

My GeoPandas:

```
geopandas                 0.8.1                      py_0    conda-forge
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `shapely.wkt.loads` to create the geometry column.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt


df['geometry'] = df.WKT.apply(wkt.loads)
df.drop('WKT', axis=1, inplace=True) #Drop WKT column

# Geopandas GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry')

#Export to shapefile
gdf.to_file('myshapefile.shp')
```

Answer (score 14):

[`geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt` API](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt.html) has been added in GeoPandas 0.9.0. It does not exist in older versions, that is why it does not work in 0.8.1.